# How can I access the data from new Error(data) in catch method?

Tags: javascript, promise

Here is my promise:

```
.then(function(response) {
    if (response.type === 'error') {
        console.log("will throw error", response);
        throw Error(response);
    }
    return extractResponseCallback(response);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("catching error", error);
    return error;
});
```

The `console.log` that is executed just prior to `throw Error(response);` shows this nice information:

```
will throw error 
{ 
  cmd: 'has_active_project',
  errorcode: 'Invalid command',
  type: 'error' 
}
```

But the `console.log("catching error", error)` in the catch method shows

```
catching error Error: [object Object]
    at /....js:18:19
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Furthermore, using console.log(JSON.stringify("catching error", error)) only shows:

```
catching error {}
```

- How can I access the data I passed to the new error?
- How should I fix this?

Comment: Try logging the `error.message` intead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to the `Error` constructor is a `string` and results in the message property on the resulting error object. You could try this if you know your custom error will be an object:

```
throw new Error(JSON.stringify(response))
```

Then you can access that message in your catch handler with

```
error.message
```

or even

```
JSON.parse(error.message)
```

if you need to interact with the individual properties for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're searching for [`console.dir()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir), it shows all properties of the passed object, and you see the normal object with interactive properties and values instead of uninformative `[object Object]` output.

From docs:

> Displays an interactive list of the properties of the specified
>   JavaScript object. The output is presented as a hierarchical listing
>   with disclosure triangles that let you see the contents of child
>   objects.
>
> In other words, console.dir is the way to see all the properties of a
>   specified JavaScript object in console by which the developer can
>   easily get the properties of the object.

Follow this way if you really need to log all these info. Notice, that when you want to see a specific field of error object, you can just log like `error.message`, it's enough for most cases.